# PHP array item partially match with database table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a PHP array

```
$array = array(
           "PHP server side scripting",
           "CSE for designing",
           "Client side scripting JavaScript, HTML etc",
           "Java object oriented programming"
         }
```

And a database table

```
+-------+-----------------+
|  id   | language        |
+-------+-----------------+
|   1   | PHP             |
|   2   | JavaScript      |
|   3   | CSE             |
|   4   | C++             |
+-------+-----------------+
```

How to match array item partially with a field of database table using query.

Required output only matched language with PHP array

```
+-------+-----------------+
|  id   | language        |
+-------+-----------------+
|   1   | PHP             |
|   2   | JavaScript      |
|   3   | CSE             |
+-------+-----------------+
```

I have tried following but did not get actual result.

```
foreach($array as $val) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE language LIKE '%$val%'";
    //remaining code
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to check is anguage a typo?

Comment: Did you misspell language? `anguage` in your sql syntax?

Comment: @Fred wow, 10 seconds apart XD

Comment: You want [fulltext searching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html). Anything else you attempt with plain `LIKE '%...%'` type matching is going to be highly ugly to build and highly slow to actually execute. w

Comment: Ok spelling is corrected. But it is not working because I have need to match `PHP server side scripting` with `PHP` but not `PHP` with `PHP server side scripting`

Comment: [**Here,** have a look at this](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/9/3/18) – @Salim

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to get all languages from db and then check what languages are in your array.

If You whant to make it in a query then you have to do something like this:

```
$array = array(
    "PHP server side scripting",
    "CSE for designing",
    "Client side scripting JavaScript, HTML etc",
    "Java object oriented programming"
);

foreach($array as $val) {
    $valArray = explode(" ", $val);
    $where = "";
    foreach ($valArray as $word) {
        $word = trim($word, ",.");
        if ($where) {
            $where .= " OR ";
        }
        $where .= " language LIKE '%$word%' ";
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE $where";
    //remaining code
}
```

But that is ugly solution